# what is the maven command to run springboot app on a desired port

Tags: maven, spring-boot

I am trying to run my springboot application using maven command on windows command prompt. 
I am trying to run the app on port 8000.
I tried the below command, but app always attempts to start at 8080 which is already occupied so start fails.

```
mvn -Dserver.port=8000 spring-boot:run
```

When I tried running the app through my IDE ( after placing server.port=8000 in application.properties file), it runs on 8000 as expected.

why does it not start on '8000' when ran through mvn command? Is there something wrong with the command?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you use Spring Boot 2.x

`mvn spring-boot:run -Dspring-boot.run.arguments=--server.port=8000`

for Spring Boot 1.x

`mvn spring-boot:run -Drun.arguments=--server.port=8000`

Comment: Thanks Dirk Deyne! 
I am using springboot 2.x, the command you have given works perfectly for me.